# How to update and replace in Cassandra a UDT field value?

Tags: cassandra

Does Cassandra support update of a UDT field value? something like replacing it with a new value?

I have user_fav_payment_method UDT and I need to replace cash with debit card:

```
update user_ratings set 
user_fav_payment_method{'cash'} = {'debit cards'}
where rating_id = 66;
```

This code is wrong but I need to do something similar to this, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useInsertUDT.html):

> In Cassandra 3.6 and later, user-defined types that include only non-collection fields can update individual field values. Update an individual field in user-defined type data using the UPDATE command. The desired key-value pair are defined in the command. In order to update, the UDT must be defined in the CREATE TABLE command as an unfrozen data type.

You can use `.` notation to update only individual fields of the non-frozen UDT, like this:

```
cqlsh> use test;
cqlsh:test> create type payment_method ( method text, data text);
cqlsh:test> create table users (id int primary key, pay_method payment_method);
cqlsh:test> insert into users (id, pay_method) values (1, {method: 'cash', data: 'usd'});
cqlsh:test> select * from users;

 id | pay_method
----+-------------------------------
  1 | {method: 'cash', data: 'usd'}

(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> update users set pay_method.method = 'card' where id = 1;
cqlsh:test> select * from users;

 id | pay_method
----+-------------------------------
  1 | {method: 'card', data: 'usd'}

(1 rows)
```